# Google Play Services and Support V4 with ProGuard... Problems?

Tags: android, google-play-services, proguard, android-proguard

I recently added proguard into a huge project using Google Play Services and Suppport V4 last version libraries.

I did not add anything about these libraries to proguard config files, i just add this:

```
-ignorewarnings
-dontobfuscate
```

Now i noticed that in proguard output file usage.txt (where you can see all code removed by proguard) it is a lot of code from google play services and android support v4.

I Checked official documentation and i did not found anything about adding exceptions for Support v4 and google play services if you are using proguard, i just found this:

> Note: ProGuard directives are included in the Play services client
>   libraries to preserve the required classes. The Android Plugin for
>   Gradle automatically appends ProGuard configuration files in an AAR
>   (Android ARchive) package and appends that package to your ProGuard
>   configuration. During project creation, Android Studio automatically
>   creates the ProGuard configuration files and build.gradle properties
>   for ProGuard use. To use ProGuard with Android Studio, you must enable
>   the ProGuard setting in your build.gradle buildTypes. For more
>   information, see the ProGuard guide.

But the problem is that i am not compiling with Android Studio, i am compiling from command line with ant and with eclipse, i am not using gradle, so i'm not sure if i must add something into proguard config file and i can't find anything in official documentation about this.

Will i face problems in the future if i don't add something in proguard config for these libraries?

Answer (score 0):

I have several projects with v4 and don't need anything special in the proguard configuration. The only thing I could find is

```
# Supporting compatibility library
-dontwarn android.support.**
```

Which does not look as if it would be harmful if removed.

**UPDATED**

For Google Play Services:

```
-keep public class com.google.android.gms.common.internal.safeparcel.SafeParcelable {
    public static final *** NULL;
}
-keepnames @com.google.android.gms.common.annotation.KeepName class *
-keepclassmembernames class * {
    @com.google.android.gms.common.annotation.KeepName *;
}
```

Comment: And what about Google Play Services with eclipse (without gradle) ?

Comment: where do you find an official source that says it is mandatory to add these lines of code into pro guard config if you are not using gradle?

Comment: Honestly, I cannot find any now. What I can tell you is that it's working for us using IAB and Google Analytics.

Comment: I tested GCM and Admob without adding any line of proguard config for Google Play Services and it is working so i'm not sure if i must add. I am very near of the 65.000 methods limit of android so i can't increment my methods count if it is not strictly necessary